# VBA - Copy template sheets to multiple sheets of another workbook if criteria met

Tags: vba, excel

I've been trying to get the code to work for the past week with no luck. I tried various modifications, which ends up giving different error codes.

The first Error I was getting was with `Set rng = Intersect(.UsedRange, .Columns(2))`

> Object doesn’t support this property or method

So then I changed this to just going through the entire column just to see if it would work : `Set rng = Range("B:B")`, when I do that then it reads through and I get an error for `Set HyperlinkedBook = Workbooks.Open(Filename:=cell.Offset(0, -1).Value)` with the error code:

> run time error 1004 Sorry we couldn’t find 24 James.xlsx

Is it possible it was moved, renamed or deleted?

I believe that this line of the code is assuming that the hyperlink should open a different workbook with that name, however this is not the case. The hyperlink on the summary sheet links through to other sheets on the same master workbook, only the templates are on a separate book.

So to overcome this I tried changing this line as well and ended up with the code below, which manages to open the template workbook, and copy just the tab name onto the first sheet and then gives an error for the following line `TemplateBook.Sheets("Red").Copy ActiveSheet.Paste`, saying

> subscript out of range

```
Sub Summary()

    Dim MasterBook As Workbook

    Set MasterBook = ActiveWorkbook
    With MasterBook    
        Dim rng As Range
        Set rng = Range("B:B")    
    End With
    Dim TemplateBook As Workbook
    Set TemplateBook = Workbooks.Open(Filename:=" C:\Users\Desktop\Example template.xlsx")

    Dim cell As Range
    For Each cell In rng
        If cell.Value = "Red" Then
            cell.Offset(0, -1).Hyperlinks(1).Follow NewWindow:=False, AddHistory:=True
            TemplateBook.Sheets("Red").Copy ActiveSheet.paste
        ElseIf cell.Value = "Blue" Then
cell.Offset(0, -1).Hyperlinks(1).Follow NewWindow:=False, AddHistory:=True
            TemplateBook.Sheets("Blue").Copy ActiveSheet.paste
        End If    
    Next cell

End Sub
```

I tried several more variations but I just can’t get it to copy the correct template, switch back to the master workbook sheet, follow through the link to correct sheet in the same master workbook, and paste the template.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A few comments about the modifications I made to your code:

1. Instead of using  the entire Column B, try to use only cells in Column B that have values inside them.
2. Try to avoid using `ActiveWorkbook`, if the code lies in the same workbook then use `ThisWorkbook` instead.
3. When you set a `Range`, fully qualify it by stating the `Workbook` and `Worksheet`, as in : `Set Rng = Sht.Range("B1:B" & Sht.Cells(Sht.Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row)`.
4. I replaced your 2 `If`s with `Select Case`, as they the result in both is the same, and it will also allow you more flexibility in the future to add more cases.
5. When you copy an entire sheet with `TemplateBook.Sheets("Red")` and paste it to another Workbook, the syntax is `TemplateBook.Sheets("Red").Copy after:=Sht`.

**Code**

```
Option Explicit

Sub Summary()

    Dim MasterBook As Workbook
    Dim Sht As Worksheet
    Dim Rng As Range

    Set MasterBook = ThisWorkbook '<-- use ThisWorkbook not ActiveWorkbook
    Set Sht = MasterBook.Worksheets("Sheet3") '<-- define the sheet you want to loop thorugh (modify to your sheet's name)                
    Set Rng = Sht.Range("B1:B" & Sht.Cells(Sht.Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row) '<-- set range to all cells in column B with values

    Dim TemplateBook As Workbook
    Set TemplateBook = Workbooks.Open(Filename:="C:\Users\Desktop\Example template.xlsx")

    Dim cell As Range

    For Each cell In Rng
        Select Case cell.Value
            Case "Red", "Blue"
                cell.Offset(0, -1).Hyperlinks(1).Follow NewWindow:=False, AddHistory:=True '<-- not so sure what values you have here
                TemplateBook.Sheets(cell.Value).Copy after:=Sht  '<-- paste after the sheet defined
            Case Else
                ' do something if you have other cases , not sure it's needed
        End Select
    Next cell

End Sub
```

---

**Edit 1:** to copy>>paste contents of the sheet, use the loop below:

```
For Each cell In Rng
    Select Case cell.Value
        Case "Red", "Blue"
            cell.Offset(0, -1).Hyperlinks(1).Follow NewWindow:=False, AddHistory:=True '<-- not so sure what values you have here
            Application.CutCopyMode = False
            TemplateBook.Sheets(cell.Value).UsedRange.Copy
            Sht.Range("A1").PasteSpecial     '<-- paste into the sheet at Range("A1")

        Case Else
            ' do something if you have other cases , not sure it's needed
    End Select
Next cell
```

---

**Edit 2:** Create a new worksheet, and then rename it with the `cell.Offset(0, -1).Value`

```
TemplateBook.Sheets(cell.Value).Copy after:=Sht

Dim CopiedSheet As Worksheet
Set CopiedSheet = ActiveSheet
CopiedSheet.Name = cell.Offset(0, -1)
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your response, I made the changes you suggested and it runs through without error, however it is not copy pasting into the pre-existing sheets, instead its creating new sheets labelled either red or blue in the same order as on column B and pasting the templates into those new sheets.  To be honest this would work even better for me, if the new sheets that are being created be labelled with the name of the adjacent cell (in column A) and hyperlinked to it. This would save me a lot more time from creating a new sheet manually for each name in column A beforehand.

Comment: @kira123 this is what you wanted according to your post, and you code. isn't it ? what do you want ? Try the loop under **Edit 1** , maybe that's what you meant

Comment: I might have not explained it clearly, so originally what I wanted was: 1. once it recognises what colour in column B e.g Red on the summary sheet, 2. open the template workbook, 3. go to the the Red template sheet, 4. copy entire sheet, 5. switch back to original MasterBook, 6. click on the hyperlinked name in the cell (column A) next to the colour (in column B)  7. this takes it to another pre-existing blank sheet in the same Masterbook, 8. paste the template for that colour. 9. repeat this process by copy pasting the correct colour template to other sheets.

Comment: However the code you provided originally made me realise it might be easier not to manually create sheets for each name in column A beforehand, because it seems like you can automatically create new sheets, but just label those new sheets with the name in column A rather than just red or blue in column B. And also hyperlink the new sheets to the names

Comment: @kira123 yep, When I copy paste template sheets I prefer to do it that way. If I answered your post, please mark as "ANSWER"

Comment: Thank you, I will do that, I would be really grateful if you could also let me know how to make it label the new sheets created with the name in column A, adjacent to the corresponding colour? and also link the sheet to the name in column A. so for example if cell B2 is red, then when a new sheet is created with the red template pasted on, the sheet should be labelled with the name in cell A2, and the new sheet should also be hyperlinked to cell A2.

Comment: @kira123 repace the section inside the `Case` with the code under **Edit 2**